# Split names into FN, LN, MI and etc in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following piece of code that works for names like 'Foo, Bar S.' and 'Foo, Bar S. (TMCS)'. But it does not work for 'Foo, Bar'. Not sure what I am doing wrong or where I am missing anything. I am getting confused keeping up with all the charindexes and lefts, rights.

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(30)

SET @FullName = 'Foo, Bar'--'Foo, Bar S.' --'Foo, Bar S. (TMCS)'
;

WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT @FullName                                        AS FN,
                LEFT(@FullName, CHARINDEX(',', RIGHT(@FullName, LEN(@FullName)-CHARINDEX(',', @FullName)))
                                + CHARINDEX(',', @FullName) - 1) AS [Last])
SELECT [Last],
       LEFT(REPLACE(@FullName, [Last] + ', ', ''), CHARINDEX(' ', REPLACE(@FullName, [Last] + ', ', '')) - 1)                                           AS [First],
       RIGHT(REPLACE(@FullName, [Last] + ', ', ''), LEN(REPLACE(@FullName, [Last] + ', ', '')) - CHARINDEX(' ', REPLACE(@FullName, [Last] + ', ', ''))) AS Middle
FROM   CTE
```

Comment: You need data cleansing software. This is a disaster SQL Server isn't equipped to handle efficiently or even very well at all.

Comment: I agree, but this is only a small piece of the whole mess. And this data exists in production. People who own the data care less if the data is damned, and I have failed to convince them of the need of proper modelling and clean data.

Comment: Consider running the data through a fuzzy lookup transformation in SSIS

Comment: @Xedni How will that split names into LN, FN and MI?

Comment: You could use a case statement to apply different logic when there is only one space character in the string.   You could also write a CLR proc that uses REGEX.

Comment: Could you give more clear examples of `input` values and desire `output`?   Also, you can check this article for enabling regular expression in SQL Server - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(30)
SET @FullName = 'Foo, Bar S.'--'Foo, Bar S.' --'Foo, Bar S. (TMCS)'

SELECT 
 LEFT(@FullName,CHARINDEX(',',@FullName)-1) AS First
,CASE WHEN LEN(@FullName) - LEN(REPLACE(@FullName, ' ', '')) < 2 Then NULL
      ELSE RIGHT(@FullName,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@FullName))-1) 
      END 
 AS Middle
,SUBSTRING(@FullName,
            CHARINDEX(' ',@FullName),
            CHARINDEX(' ',@FullName,Charindex(' ',@FullName+' ',+1) +1) - CHARINDEX(' ',@FullName))
 AS Last
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code does the job:

```
declare @test table (Name varchar(200))

insert @test
select 'Smith, John T' union all
select 'Alice, Smith T. (tmsc)' union all
select 'Johnson, Paul'

select * from @test

-- do the work
select LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) - 1) LastName, 
        SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) = 0 THEN LEN(Name) + 1 ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) END - CHARINDEX(', ', Name) - 2) FirstName,
        RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) = 0 THEN LEN(Name) ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) END) Mid
from @test
```

Comment: Thanks all for looking into this.